# C first letter to uppercase ignores first word

Tags: c, string, whitespace, toupper

I am trying to make every first word letter capital, but it ignores the first word and jumps to second. 
"apple macbook" should be "Apple Macbook", but it gives me "apple Macbook". If I add `printf(" %c", toupper(string[0]));` before for loop and change `p=1` in for loop it gives me correct result, but if string starts with a space then it will fail.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char string[] = "apple macbook";
    int p;
    for(p = 0; p<strlen(string); p++)
    {
        if(string[p] == ' ')
        {
            printf(" %c", toupper(string[p+1]));
            p++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", string[p]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obviously the code doesn't work because the very first letter in the string is a special case with no space before it. You have to treat that special case separately. Also, you need to iterate from 0 to `strlen(string)-1`, otherwise your program will always destroy the null terminator and then crash when a space is the last letter of the string.

Comment: Are you surprised? There is no space before "Apple".

Comment: You test for a whitespace character in your if statement. The next character will be converted to upper case. Try `if (p==0 || string[p] == '  ')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple work around can be as follows:

```
 for(p = 0; p<strlen(string); p++)
    {
        if(p == 0 || string[p - 1] == ' ')
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(string[p]));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", string[p]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @gsamaras: You say that as if changing the input string were such a good idea... `:-)`

Comment: Hmmm @MOehm you are right, I will update my question!

Comment: I guess there can be problem with potencially acces to string[p-1] while p will be 0, can't ? (Of course, in fact there is fixed by first decision, but .. ) 
Or char[-1] will return '\0'  as "null char" ?

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx If p is zero, it will not go for next condition, ie, `string[p - 1] == ' '`

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx: C's short-circuit evaluation guarantees that the expression right of the logical or `||` isn't evaluated when the left expression is true, which means the the whole expression must be true.

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx: Not even potentially. This is guaranteed and a lot of code relies on it.

Comment: Ok guys :D :D ..
And btw theoretically what will return "1 position before zero index" ? will be an exception, null, or something else? :)

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx: That would be an array access out of bounds, which leads to undefined behaviour. But the presented code is well-behaved.

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx: that's undefined, so it's best to check before you do so and prevent doing this if `index` may be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
char string[] = "apple macbook";
```

to this:

```
char string[] = " apple macbook";
```

and you will get what you want.

The reason is that in your loop, you search for a space to change the letter afterwards.

---

However, niyasc's answer is better, since it does not alter the input string but the logic of your program.

I mostly did that to exploit the reason that you are getting the behaviour you encountered, so that you were urged to change your logic by yourself. :)